# Not updating the Value in HTML angular 5/6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am not able to detect changes in this condition.

Below is the code ts and html.

```
print(){ 
this.hideBoolean = true;
        let printContents, popupWin;
        printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
        popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>
          body{  width: 99%;}
            label { font-weight: 400;
                    font-size: 13px;
                    padding: 2px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                  }
            table, td, th {
                   border: 1px solid silver;
                    }
                    table td {
                   font-size: 13px;
                    }

                     table th {
                   font-size: 13px;
                    }
              table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 98%;
                    }
                th {
                    height: 26px;
                    }
          </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
        );
        popupWin.document.close();

    }
```

--------------HTML------------

```
    <button type="button" (click)="print()"> Print</button> 

<div id="print-section" >
<div *ngIf="hideBoolean"> value .</div>
```

So main issues is while clicking the button. boolean is not working properly,
first click wont work after second click it will work.
 Im not getting the proper issue ? anyone help me.! Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question in a better way? I haven't understand a single thing you said.

Comment: i have created two button for hiding and showing in the print. I am getting value after second click not with first click.

Comment: So you want to be hide by default, and after the first click you want the div to be shown?

Comment: did u get my question ? i have edited commet.

Comment: Alright, I think I got it. Your issue is that you have to click two times in order to see the content of this line : `<div *ngIf="hideBoolean"> value .</div>`, right?

Comment: yes, you are right .

Comment: is `hideBoolean` setted to false by default? (for example: `public hideBoolean = false;`)

Comment: yes it is declared. public hideBoolean = false;

Comment: if you just keep `this.hideBoolean = true;` inside your print function, is working at first try? Or you have to click it two times?

Comment: another button  
printDouble() {
this.hideBoolean = true; 
this.print()
}
i have called like this.

Comment: and its not working with first click.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkjpzy have a look here. Start from this and edit your code starting from this example. If you have problem we can start talking in chat

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hu9grc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html 
 can u check this example ?

Comment: both of buttons works fine to me on your stackblitz, what's the problem?

Comment: no.. output is not working. i have to click two times for output. check properly.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after the comments, I finally solved the problem.

your html:

```
<span (click)="printSingle()" class="btn">Print single</span>
<span (click)="printDouble()" class="btn">Print Double</span>

<div id="print-section">
  single print
<div *ngIf="showHideDiv">double print</div>
</div>
```

your ts:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  showHideDiv = false;

  constructor(private  changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  toggle(){
    this.showHideDiv = !this.showHideDiv;
  }
  printDouble(){
this.showHideDiv= true;
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
this.print();
  }
  printSingle(){
    this.showHideDiv= false;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.print();
  }
  print(){ 

        let printContents, popupWin;
        printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
        popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>
          body{  width: 99%;}
            label { font-weight: 400;
                    font-size: 13px;
                    padding: 2px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                  }
            table, td, th {
                   border: 1px solid silver;
                    }
                    table td {
                   font-size: 13px;
                    }

                     table th {
                   font-size: 13px;
                    }
              table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 98%;
                    }
                th {
                    height: 26px;
                    }
          </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
        );
        popupWin.document.close();

    }
}
```

I've added `changeDetectorRef` and use it this way because what it does is to force (basically) the render of some parts that are blocked. Let me know if this solved, but in the stackblitz edited this way it works fine.